# How can I mouse-scroll around a 2D tile map in pygame?

Tags: python, scroll, pygame

I am trying to play around with pygame and I have using some examples that I found to learn and create a simple. My next goal is to create a 2D tile map bigger than the screen size and then being able to scroll around with the mouse. I would like to make something similar as a strategic game, where if you move the mouse to the edges of the screen, the "camara" will move in that direction, showing that part of the map (I would like also to stop the camara if it reaches the end of the map). At this moment, if I hover the mouse over the edges, it will only move once.

```
import pygame, os
from pygame.locals import *

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 5*40
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 7*40

#functions to create our resources
def load_image(name, colorkey=None):
    try:
        image = pygame.image.load(name) 
    except pygame.error, message:
        print 'Cannot load image:', name
        raise SystemExit, message
    image = image.convert_alpha()
    if colorkey is not None:
        if colorkey is -1:
            colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
        image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
    return image, image.get_rect()

#classes for our game objects
class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = pygame.Rect(100,100, width, height)

    def apply(self, rect):
        l, t, w, h = rect

        if 0 <= self.state[0] <= (SCREEN_WIDTH/5):
            l += 10
        elif (SCREEN_WIDTH - (SCREEN_WIDTH/5)) < self.state[0] <= SCREEN_WIDTH:
            l -=10

        if 0 <= self.state[1] <= (SCREEN_HEIGHT/5):
            t += 10
        elif (SCREEN_HEIGHT - (SCREEN_HEIGHT/5)) < self.state[1] <= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            t -=10

        return rect.move(l,t)

    def update(self):
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.state.topleft = pos
        #self.state = self.camera_func(self.state)

def complex_camera(camera):
    l, t, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l, -t, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling at the left edge
    l = max(-(camera.width-SCREEN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling at the right edge
    t = max(-(camera.height-SCREEN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling at the bottom
    t = min(0, t)                           # stop scrolling at the top
    return pygame.Rect(l, t, w, h)

def main ():

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])

    pygame.display.set_caption("W40K")

    grasstile = pygame.image.load('./textures/grass.png')
    watertile = pygame.image.load('./textures/water.png')
    waterbeach = pygame.image.load('./textures/dirt.png')

    grassrect = grasstile.get_rect()
    waterrect = watertile.get_rect()
    waterb = waterbeach.get_rect()

    TILESIZE = 40

    tilemap = [

        [grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],   
        [grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],
        [waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],
        [grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],
        [grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],
        [watertile,grasstile,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],
        [watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],
        [grasstile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],
        [grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],
        [grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,grasstile,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],
        [grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,watertile,grasstile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],
        [grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],
        [grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],
        [grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],
        [grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach,watertile,watertile,watertile,waterbeach,waterbeach,waterbeach,grasstile,grasstile,waterbeach],
    ]

    #Creates surface of the background
    map_surface = pygame.Surface((len(tilemap[0])*TILESIZE, len(tilemap)*TILESIZE))
    #Display the surface
    for y,row in enumerate(tilemap):
        for x,tile_surface in enumerate(row):
            map_surface.blit(tile_surface,(x*TILESIZE,y*TILESIZE))

    total_level_width = len(tilemap[0]) * 40
    total_level_height = len(tilemap) * 40

    camera = Camera(complex_camera,total_level_width, total_level_height)

    #mouse = Mouse()
    #allsprites = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain((mouse))

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while 1:
        clock.tick(60)

    #Handle Input Events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                return

        screen.fill(BLACK)

        #Camera moves.
        camera.update()

        #Display background.
        screen.blit(map_surface, camera.apply(waterrect))

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

pygame.quit()
```

I think that the problem is in the camara function and the apply function, but I have no clue to improve this and make the camara work properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody wants to answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard for me to say exactly what is wrong with your sode ( i got too little experience in coding ) , but i just realised movin screen by mouse in my script and i did this :

```
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH,WINDOWHEIGHT),32)

Map=pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Image','MAP.png')).convert_alpha()

startX,startY=0,0                   # starting coordinates for Map

while 1:
    screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(Map,(startX,startY))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == MOUSEMOTION :
            mousepos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if WINDOWHEIGHT-mousepos[1]<50:     # if  y-position of mouse is 50 pixel far from lower edge ..
        startY -= 5                     # ..move Map by 5 px
    if mousepos [1]<50:
        startY += 5
    if mousepos [0]<50 :
        startX += 5
    if WINDOWWIDTH - mousepos[0]<50:
        startX -= 5

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Hope this can suggest you an idea how to improve your code